# How to get an element's id from its classname

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to know how can I get the id of an element based on a specific class name? In the following `HTML` I want to retrieve the `id` of the div having class `tab-pane active`

```
<div class="tab-pane active" id="Basic">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [**.attr()**](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) as shown :-

```
var id = $('div.tab-pane.active').attr('id')
```

OR

```
var id = $('.tab-pane.active').attr('id')
```

**Side Note :-** I am assuming that you have only one element with class `tab-pane active` in your DOM otherwise you have to use `$.each()` to loop through all div with class `tab-pane active`

Comment: Works! And yes I only have one element with this class

Comment: @HumaAli..Great..happy to help you..;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `attr()` function to retrieve any attribute of an element.

```
var id = $(".tab-pane").attr("id");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code.

```
 var id=$('.tab-pane.active').attr('id')
```